# Jupyter websocket issue

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I have a debian Jupyter running on port 8888.

I want to make it easier to connect to my server,so I have a node.js
app running that forwards request to  jupyter.mydomain.com:80 to 
port 8888, andother domains to other ports.

This way I dont have to remember the ports of different apps, and instead
can refer to the server with different dns names. All the different names
are setup as a links in the dns server.

Now Jupyter works this way; but the Websockets that report the result of
calculations do not due to security error.

Is there any setting how I can get this to work?

Regards

Andreas

Comment: so the node app doesn't forward the websocket requests? or are the websocket requests not made to port 80?

Answer (score 0):

[node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) is a node proxy that supports websockets. Your node app that's proxying requests must also proxy websocket connections.

[JupyterHub](http://jupyterhub.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is a multi-user server for spawning and authenticating single-user notebook servers, and it uses [configurable-http-proxy](https://github.com/jupyter/configurable-http-proxy), a subclass of node-http-proxy that adds some live configuration, to relay connections to notebooks.  If you use NHP or CHP for your proxy app, the websockets should work.

From the node-http-proxy [readme](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy#proxying-websockets):

> You can activate the websocket support for the proxy using `ws:true`
>   in the options.
>
> ```
> //
> // Create a proxy server for websockets
> //
> httpProxy.createServer({
>   target: 'ws://localhost:9014',
>   ws: true
> }).listen(8014);
> ```